# webpack config "import webpack from webpack" not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

the problem:
I'm trying to upgrade my babel/react version, and updated and added the needed packages,
but now my webpack config is not working

```
'use strict';
//webpack.config.babel.js
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

these are the first lines of my config
and running `webpack -d --watch` throws the next error

```
/Users/alan.carrasco/source/webpack.config.babel.js:3
import webpack from 'webpack';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

installing the latest webpack version fixed!